# Crystal Report Show Total Only On Last Page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula that calculated price total of an invoice eg. @vtotal. The invoice page could span from 1 to n page. I would like to show the total only on last page. How do I do that?

I have searched and tried on some suggestions using report footer, but it does not work as it implies, the report footer always show in tandem with page footer.

I have also tried using formula:

```
if PageNumber = TotalPageCount then
{@vtotal}
```

It still display 0 on pages with PageNumber < TotalPage Count.

How to do it correctly to only show on last page? And nothing on other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create group over invoice ID (or whatever field identifies invoice uniquely) and show your formula in group footer.

/edit after comments/

Alternative way is to supress some formulas in page footer section. Place your `{@vtotal}` into page footer (like it was initially) and create suppress formula for it, with content like

```
{PageNumber < TotalPageCount}
```

You need to somehow account for situations, when you print more than single invoice - if this is possible for your setup of course.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have created the group, now group footer appears only on last page. But page footer still appear on every page along with group footer. Or, how can I align group footer with the page footer? As group footer appears on random Y position.

Comment: In section expert, you can force group footer print at bottom of page. Do you need page footers at all?

Comment: Have enable print bottom of page, report footer still at arbitrary position and above the page footer. Yes, I do need page footer to show subtotal (only) of items displayed so far. And all other summary values (discount, total) at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: I added other idea to answer.

Comment: I tried to use "if PageNumber = TotalPageCount then {@vtotal}" in formula in Page Footer. But on page (other than last page), it shows 0. And I can't use surpress if zero (as zero is a valid value in my invoice). In above logic, I didn't even use else 0, but it becomes 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: I hinted you to use suppress formula:) In field formatting dialog, you can press button next to Supress checkbox and write there conditional formula (you have to check Suppress checkbox too) - then your formula result is displayed only when suppress condition is false.

Comment: Thanks @Arvo. Surpress formula did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can write Grand Total in **Report Footer**. So it will display in only last page.